# Textbox in xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.4, xlsxwriter

I am trying to insert a textbox into a chartsheet using xlsxwriter in python 3.4 to give more information about the chart. Is there a way to insert a textbox into a chartsheet? I could insert it into a worksheet and not a chartsheet.
Also, is there a way to edit the legend using xlsxwriter? I have a row of 30 values and I want to plot in a batch of 10
`batch1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`
I dont want "batch1" to be shown in the legend 3 times. I want to customize it as `iteration1`,`iteration2`,`iteration3`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting a textbox into a chart, or chartsheet, isn't supported.

In relation to the second question, you can remove items from the legend in XlsxWriter using the `delete_series` feature of `set_legend()`:

```
# Delete/hide series index 0 and 2 from the legend.
chart.set_legend({'delete_series': [0, 2]})
```

[image]

See the docs on [`set_legend()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-set-legend)

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out for me. I have used set_legend to hide the legend. But is there a way to modify it? For example, in the graph that you posted, I want `Series2` to be shown as `Iteration1` without changing the row/column in the xls.

Comment: You can change the name of the series in the `add_series()` method. See for example: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_column.html